# class + proc glmselect + dummy variables

Tags: sas

Looking at this code:

```
proc glmselect data=analysisData testdata=testData plots=asePlot;
    class c1 c2 c3;
    model y = c1|c2|c3|x1|x2|x3|x4|x5|x5|x6|x7|x8|x9|x10
    |x11|x12|x13|x14|x15|x16|x17|x18|x19|x20 @2
    / selection=forward(stop=none);
run;
```

Taken from [here](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi31/207-31.pdf) does the line:

```
class c1 c2 c3;
```

introduce dummy variables automatically or am I generally better of to introduce them myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class statement does create the dummy variables for you.

Documentation here:
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/68162/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_glmselect_syntax03.htm

You can use the `OUTDESIGN=` option on the `PROC GLMSELECT` output the selected model which should include the dummy variables.
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/68162/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_glmselect_syntax01.htm

Comment: Thanks. So the short answer is yes. Are there any more exhaustive tutorials/books on this? I am a SAS beginner and I find that the online doc does not provide enough details.

Comment: No problem.  I am not aware of any, but that doesn't mean they don't exist.  The documentation definitely has a learning curve.  Once you are up it, you can find just about anything you want.

Comment: Yeah I hope so (-: Thanks.